# Health data duplicates

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, data, health.app

Why do several apps (example: Runkeeper) generate duplicate data in the Health App?

Is this a bug or something I can turn off?
[image: Runkeeper duplicates]

Comment: I don't have the app, but is there a loop where another app reads data or writes workout data so that you have a feedback effect? I've seen that on the workout section of health.app, but I don't have a RunKeeper section to test. FWIW, Runmeter does not have this issue, but I understand a lot of people like the keeper app.

Comment: Thanks - I've been looking for a loop as well and though i thought I had found it a couple of times, this still occurs. This also seems to plague other apps writing to Apple Health, at least on my phone.

Comment: Agreed - all apps I'm using blanket request read/write to so many parts, that it's hard to remember to re-map the data flow for each new app. I'm starting to deny all requests and then add them manually from the health app so I'm able to see what other apps read/write each category of data.